# Does every layer of an equivariant composite function have to be equivariant?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions, equivariant-maps

For example, given a composite function $f(x)=f_1(f_2(f_3(x)))$, if $f(x)$ is equivariant to the group $G$ (e.g. $SO(3)$), then is it necessary for $f_1$,$f_2$,$f_3$ to be equivariant to $G$? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, the answer is no. For instance, let $S^1$ act on $\Bbb{R}^2$ by rotation. Define $\phi:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$. $\phi\circ \phi=\mathrm{Id}$, which is of course $S^1$-equivariant. However, $\phi$ and the $S^1$ action do not commute. For instance rotate $(0,1)$ by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians counterclockwise.

Comment: Thanks, Alekos. It seems that the influence of the part that breaks equivariance must be offset then to ensure the equivariance of the composite function, right?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.